# What can I do with ginger syrup?

Tags: syrup, ginger

I got a bottle of (supposedly high quality) ginger syrup for Christmas. I've never seen or tasted it before, so I have no idea how to use it.
Since I like ginger, I considered just diluting it with water and drinking it. Or adding it to tea. **Can it somehow be used for cooking or cocktails?** I have tried searching, but my google-fu failed once again.

Comment: @ashes999: If you're trying to be helpful to a new user, you could at least clarify; some of them are acceptable: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/740/can-i-ask-about-how-to-use-a-specific-ingredient-aka-culinary-uses-guidelines This question is a bit borderline, in my view; there are a lot of uses that I *was* able to find by searching. It's not about "well-received"; it's about clearly answerable questions that will be of use to the OP and to others.

Comment: @Jefromi really? That's surprising. I got a pretty good slap in the face when I had a question that *smelled* like a "what can I do with ..." question. Good to see things are changing.

Comment: @ashes999: That link on meta is *old*. If things are changing, they're getting stricter. *Some* questions like this are acceptable, as described in the linked question/answer - in ingredients that wouldn't normally be used. This one is iffy, though; I had already voted to close it, because as I said, there are a lot of uses that are easily findable. (I just want ver to understand *why*, and what sorts of questions *are* a good fit for this site.) Questions which are clearly bad ("what can I do with broccoli") should indeed be closed rapidly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things you can combine it with:

- smoothies
- ice cream
- pancakes
- oatmeal
- tea
- hot almond milk
- rhubarb pie
- fruit salad
- dumplings (you can use the syrup as a sauce)

You can make ginger ale with it (or put some in regular lemonade), or cocktails (e.g. Dark Ginger Daiquiri; Ginger Rogers; [here](http://www.barnonedrinks.com/drinks/by_ingredient/g/ginger-syrup-2322.html)'s a short list of cocktails containing ginger syrup). You can make cookies with it (e. g. [this](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/soft-ginger-molasses-cookies-and-ginger-syrup-recipe)).

Ginger syrup is  basically ginger, water and sugar. So practically everything that goes with ginger, will go with ginger syrup.

Answer (score 2):

Boil some water with a slice of lemon in it, add ginger syrup and honey. Very tasty, and fantastic when you have a cold.

As for cocktail, I once tasted a very nice vodka-based cocktail with ginger. Not sure what the exact recipe was, but it had vodka, ginger, lemon and mint. I guess substituting ginger with ginger syrup would do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I love ginger syrup and use it for many things. I have just found that it is great for caramelising onions.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a use I haven't heard before, but it's quite vague. Would you please add some details, especially a recipe? What's the exact method? Do you use it instead of butter or oil? Does it require a different level of heat on the burner? How much do you use, for instance, do you cover the bottom of the pan? Does it impart ginger flavor into the onions? Because ginger syrup has sugar, do the onions taste sweeter? Our site's different than others, so please check out our [help], especially the [ask] page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

King Arthur has a recipe for ginger bread-yeasted-that includes a recipe for ginger syrup. You could substitute the bottled stuff. I've made it and it lasts a long time. Used it in a pinch for fresh ginger in a stir fry, also when canning peaches, pear or peach pie, mix with soda for ginger ale.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the recipe... that would be helpful!